# PHP Set Process Title in Apache

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way to set the process title for a PHP script running under Apache (`mod_php`)?  Typically, if I look at the output of `top`, I just see a bunch of copies of `apache2`, which is not usefull.  I am using Ubuntu Linux in case that matters.

I have found the PECL [proctitle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setproctitle.php) extension, but it seems that it doesn't work very well.  Plus, it's an extension, meaning I would have to get it installed, etc.  I would prefer another way.

I also found the [cli_set_process_title](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cli-set-process-title.php) function, which seems to do what I want, but it only works in CLI mode.  Is there an Apache version of this function?

Comment: [PECL setproctitle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setproctitle.php)?

Comment: It sounds as though you're trying to determine what PHP scripts are running in Apache. If that's the case, a much better solution is available in the [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) Apache module.